# Why do linear constraints always form a convex set?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

When doing linear programming, according to my professor, linear constraints always form a convex set. Why is this true?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612887/constraint-set-of-canonical-linear-programming-problem-is-convex

Comment: If two points satisfy a linear constraint, so do all points on the line between them. For multiple constraints, this applies to each individually.

Comment: The key idea here is that an intersection of convex sets is a convex set.

Comment: A linear constraint is either a subspace (equality) or a closed half space ($\le$). @BrianBorchers comment is the essence.

Answer (score 1):

If $Ax_1 = b, Ax_2 =b$

i.e $x_1,x_2$ belongs to the set then
for $0<=k<=1$

$kAx_1 + (1-k)Ax_2 = kb + (1-k)b$

or $A(kx_1 + (1-k)x_2) = b$

i.e
$kx_1 + (1-k)x_2 $ also belongs to the set. Therefore the set is convex.

Comment: use underscores _ for sub-indices, please.